# How to close a class the extends JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I am relatively new at java and I am making a HangMan Game but I am facing a problem right now.In particular, I want to close the frame of the program to open a new one when someone finds the word but since my class there extends JPanel dispose() isn't an available solution. So, what should I do to close this frame? ( bare in mind that its object is defined at another class, the one that calls that specific one.) Here is part of my code: ( please forgive me for displaying so many lines ) I just want to know how I can close this window without exiting the whole program, Thanks for your time
:) )

EDIT: Thanks guys, I really learned a lot through this '' comment section''. I am grateful for your quick responds and I hope that in the future i will not ask such a silly question again:) 
PS: I actually used the CardLayout to solve my problem. I don't really see thought how this question is similar to  '' How to programmatically close a JFrame '' since in this one I can't use the dispose method because i am extending a JPanel.

```
 import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
//import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable{

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
 super.paintComponent(g);
 this.setBackGround(Color.BLACK);

}


public void run()
{
}
 }
```

Comment: Please post the [minimum amount of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will demonstrate your problem. This is far too much irrelevant code to expect anyone to read.

Comment: *"I want to close the frame of the program to open a new one*" - Plese consider alternatives like a `CardLayout`, the [use of multiple `JFrame`s](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/4857909) isn't good practise.

Comment: *" I want to close the frame of the program to open a new one when someone finds the word"* - Don't. Reset the state of the game to the beginning again

Answer (score 2):

> I want to close the frame of the program to open a new one when someone finds the word

The simple answer is, don't. Instead, reset the state of the game to a initial state and update the UI accordiningly

Answer (score 0):

For your problem:

- You can just extend `JFrame` instead of `JPanel`.
- You can set the close operation of the JFrame you make in your constructor (`frame`). Use `setDefaultCloseOperation` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)
- You can store the `JFrame` you have in your constructor as an instance field and call dispose on it later (whenever you need to re-start the game).

Also, using a text field with a keyboard listener or a "submit" button may make this easier - you won't need the 26 letter buttons and the UI would be much more intuitive.

Also, using arrays would make many of your other variables disappear.

Comment: but, can i use the paintComponent method without extending jpanel?

Comment: No. What exactly do you need paintComponent for? You only seem to be updating the UI when the user clicks.

Comment: i am actually drawing the hangman in the program

Comment: *"but, can i use the paintComponent method without extending jpanel?"* - No

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, it's a bad idea to extend from top level containers like `JFrame`, 99% of the time, you're not adding new functionality to the class and you're just locking yourself into a single use case. 99% of the time, you can achieve the same results as extending from `JFrame` as you can by simply creating a new instance of it when you need it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrap the entire Game class in a parent class that can control the creation of new JFrames, and also the addition of a Game JPanel to it?

That would logically separate the components, because it can be confusing when a component class - to be added to a container - is extended and then proceeds to create its own container (this is actually fine if the UI setup is done *once*, but possibly not for a repeatable process).

Answer (score 0):

The `JPanel` alone cannot be visible, you need to have it in some sort of container. This container is received by `panel.getParent()`.

Having that, you can remove yourself from the parent container.

This sample class has a `JButton` that removes the panel from the view hierarchy when clicked.

```
public static class APanel extends JPanel {
    public APanel() {
        super();

        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setText("Hello World!");
        btn.addActionListener(e -> {
            ((JButton) e.getSource()).setText("Boo!");
            final Container parent = APanel.this.getParent();
            parent.remove(APanel.this);
            parent.repaint();
        });
        add(btn);
    }
}
```

Comment: this actually helped me with another program of mine but is there something i can do to close this specific window or do i have to use CardLayout? thx for your time

Comment: @Notorious_Hacker What do you mean with "this specific window"? You have a `JPanel` presented in your code. The panel is not a window (`JFrame` is a window). A `JPanel`, beeing a `JComponent` can be `add()`ed and `remove()`d from a `Container` class. It cannot be closed. Btw: If you found my comment useful, it is good practice on SO to vote up.